# While trying to reinstall Windows I chose "Delete Partition", did it erase my data?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

I wanted to resintall windows and I wanted to format the partition. It failed. Then I chose - delete partition. But Windows still didn't want to install cuz I had UEFI iso. I rebooted. Did my selection "Delete Partition" in Windows' Partition manager erased my data?

Comment: possibly,  you havent provided enough information to say for sure.

Comment: Do you recall how many partitions there were? What they might have been named? And which of those partitions you deleted?

Comment: So did you do anything after deleting the partition? How did you determine formatting it failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your previous Windows installation was just on one partition ("C Drive") and your files and folders were there on that one partition, and this is the partition that was deleted, what has happened is that your partition has been overwritten.

What it does NOT mean is that your data has necessarily been overwritten.

If you consider yourself technically competent, you could head over to our big data recovery community wiki (that's a big word that means "answer"): [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

If you'd rather leave this to the professionals, you should find a local computer support service that can do data recovery. If you only did the reinstall recently, there's a good chance a large amount of your data could be recovered, but it's going to cost a bit of money.

If you want to try it yourself, just know that many of the same actions that can work to recover your data can also make it harder for the professionals to recover it if you fail and choose to use them later.